# A piecewise inequality not simplified to True

Tags: symbolic, piecewise, inequalities

```
In = Simplify[-a + Piecewise[{{-b, t > c}}] < 0, {a > 0, b > 0, c > 0}]
Out = Piecewise[{{-b, t > c}}] < a
```

Why the result is not evaluated to true?

Comment: Include [`PiecewiseExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PiecewiseExpand.html), i.e., `Assuming[{a > 0, b > 0, c > 0}, Simplify@PiecewiseExpand[-a + Piecewise[{{-b, t > c}}] < 0]]`